# GitHub Mylyn Connector installation

Tags: eclipse, github, eclipse-plugin

If i try to install the GitHub Mylyn Connector, i get this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse GitHub integration with task focused interface 3.3.0.201403021825-r (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.201403021825-r)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse GitHub integration with task focused interface 3.3.0.201403021825-r (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.201403021825-r) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group 3.7.0' but it could not be found
```

- I could not find any other post with this error-message :/

I already installed EGit, and I also tried to install the Github Mylyn Connector with the Eclipse Marketplace but it didn't change anything.

I use Eclipse 4.3 for Mac OS X

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The GitHub Mylyn Connector has been broken in the Eclipse Marketplace for at least a month now.

To manually install it, visit the EGit home page

http://eclipse.org/egit/download/

And copy the update link you want to use. I use the following:

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates

In Eclipse, go to

**Help** > **Install New Software...** > Click the **Add...** button

In the *Name* field type **GitHub Mylyn Connector** for future reference, and past the update URL in the *Location* field.

Click the **OK** button.

You should now see the Collaboration option, and you can expand it to verify that it will install "Eclipse GitHub integration with task focused interface".

Click **Next**, agree to the terms, **Next**, have Eclipse restart, and you should be ready to go.

After Eclipse starts up again, open the **Task Repositories** view > right-click in the view > click **Add Task Repository..** > Choose **GitHub Issues** > Then continue on with configuring for GitHub and creating a New Query.

Comment: Today, 2014-Nov-20, the [MarketPlace Page](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/github-mylyn-connector#.VG3lC612PxQ) still reports the same kind of error from other users.

Comment: I have egit installed yet **GitHub Issues** is not among the options on the **Add Task Repository** dialog box. It always used to work. Not sure when it stopped. Or why. My GitHub Issues category is just empty now and I can't find a way to configure it.